# Do these uses of "bright" seem unnatural/awkward?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

A number of my (Slavic) non-native English speaking colleagues have a tendency to use the adjective "bright" (or the adverb brightly) in contexts it doesn't seem natural. For example, "**create a bright mood**" or "**experience bright emotions**." I know *why* this is - it's about the way яркий and similar words in other languages are used - but it sounds awkward translated into English.

As one of a handful of native speakers in the company I've been asked to give a talk to an extracurricular seminar on improving English and sounding more natural. This is mostly about using articles, word order and other small things. However, it also covers common but more nuanced mistakes, like using "complicated" instead of "difficult," and I wanted to include this as well.

The problem is, I can't quite work out why it sounds unnatural.

Looking through some dictionary definitions, "bright" can be defined as meaning happy or lively. That's fine, and often this is illustrated with some variation of the obvious example "a bright smile." The problem is, it still doesn't sound natural to speak of emotions, moods, feelings, etc. as being bright, or expressed brightly.

Does anyone know if there's some reason to this? Or is this perfectly legitimate usage and I'm just crazy?

Comment: I think it sounds unnatural simply because native English speakers don't really do it, and anything you're not used to hearing can sound a bit odd.

Comment: Ehm, what's wrong with a bright mood? Can't moods be brightened?

Comment: That's part of the problem, for me. "He really brightened the mood" sounds fine. "He can create a bright mood" sounds awkward somehow. If I can find some way to describe this - some rule that makes sense - then I can include it. 

If not, I can't (because, as nnnnnn says, it may just be because "we don't do it that way" and that's somewhat confusing advice to ESL learners, no matter how advanced they may be).

Comment: I agree with @MrLister that "create a bright mood" sounds fine. I don't know about Mr Lister but I'm an old Br English speaker but maybe it's a generational or linguistic origin difference.